# Why are gravity and spring-force conservative forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, work, potential-energy

I know that the amount of work does not depend on the followed path but on the position when speaking about conservative forces. But could someone please prove/explain why exactly those two are [conservative forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force)?

Has it something to do with the potential energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conservative force has the property that the work done in moving a particle between two points is independent of the path taken. It implies that the force is dependent only on the position of the particle. Now we can use this idea to define a function called the potential energy.

It is a conservative force that gives rise to the concept of potential energy and not the other way round. If the force were non conservative, the force would not be dependent on position only and thus we could not have defined a potential energy function.

A simpler way to find out whether a force is conservative or not is to find out the closed line integral of force, i.e $\oint dr F$ and convert it into the area integral of the curl of the force by using Green's theorem, i.e
$$ \oint  F dr = \int_A (\nabla \times F) da$$. Thus if the curl of the force is zero, it automatically means that the force is zero. It is now trivial to see that the gravitational as well as the spring force are conservative as the curl of both forces vanish.

Comment: "a simpler way" you made me laugh. Unfortunaltely my knowledge of mathematics isn't advanced enough to be able to apply this formula ((.
I haven't seen that type of integrals (yet) during my engineering education

Comment: "a more simpler way, :P" is to see that since $F$ only depends on position, then a closed integral gives zero as the answer, for the result after integration is only a function of position. So any force depending only on position is by default a conservative force. The "advanced mathematics" is a general answer as it can be used to find out for any force $F$ if it is conservative or not.

Comment: Why do you use the nabla operator in this formula?

Comment: so the nabhla operator crossed with a quantity is called the curl of the quantity. It operates just in the same fashion like the cross product $A \times B$. In general it is much easier to find out if some multivariable force is conservative or not using this method. e.g, if I have a force given by $F = x^2 + xy -2z^3$, then its very easy to compute its curl and see if the force is conservative or not.

Comment: The curl of a vector field is a measure of how much the vector field rotates in the vicinity of the point at which it is computed. As you can visualize easily, the vector fields for both the gravitational force as well as spring force are strictly radial. Therefore they should be conservative.

Comment: let's say I apply the nabla operator on the scalar field, which represents gravity around us. If the gravity vector equals the result of the nabla operation. We have a conservative force. Please correct me if I am wrong so far. But what does this has to do with the "path independence" ?

No matter what direction you go, there will be no increase of gravitational force. So the nabla operation will just give you a constant value, which is always equal to the gravity-force vector. And as it s equal we have there a conservative force.

Comment: $(\nabla \times F)$ for gravitation gives zero. So gravitation is path independent.

Comment: Would it be correct to then say: the operation results in a zero-vector. So the vector points to nowhere as there is no increase in gravity anywhere. But in this case. Why does the amount of work exerted by gravity depends on its position? As the gravity is the same everywhere.

Comment: please see that in the formula given in the answer i used a close integral..please refer to some advanced engineering mathematics book to understand more about curl etc.

Comment: indeed that is what I am doing. Thank you for all the explanation so far. This clarified a lot. But the part about the closed line integral is the only thing which is not clear yet. I understand the nabla-part. I now know what a closed line integral is. But I just don't see what the closed line integral has to do with the gravity here. I know that the integral of a closed path is 0. And the result of the nabla operation is zero. But I don't see how you can consider gravity as a closed path or something like that in our case. What exaclty is the closed path in this case please?

Comment: @privetDruzia As you know, force times distance is the work done, so if you do the closed loop integral of $F dr$, you obtain the work gained around that loop. If it comes non-zero, it means that you have started from a position, went around and came back to the same position and now you have more, or less energy. In a conservative force, the potential energy only depends on position, so going around a loop should give you 0 work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is pretty late, but I'm hoping it'll help at least a little. The idea here is, of course, using Green's Theorem:

$$\oint \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf r = \int_A (\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F ) \; \mathrm{d}\mathbf a $$

Here, you're asking about the line integral around a closed path. When using this equation, you end up making any arbitrary closed path (in other words, you can choose *any* path as long as it's closed). To choose a path, imagine an object (like a box, for example), and imagine the box under the influence of the gravitational field. Move the box in space in any direction, along any path you so choose. To make a closed path, move the box back to its starting point at the end of the path.

The nice trick about Green's Theorem is that, instead of calculating the closed line integral (which can be messy since the maths isn't so nice), you can instead calculate

$$ \int_A (\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F ) \; \mathrm{d}\mathbf a $$

which can sometimes be a lot easier. In the case of gravity, electric force, or a spring force, it turns out that $$\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F = \mathbf 0 \;.$$ So it follows that $$ \oint \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf r = \int_A (\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F ) \; \mathrm{d}\mathbf a =\int_A \mathbf 0 \; \mathrm{d}\mathbf a = 0 $$ and $$ \oint \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf r = 0 $$ This is nice because it works for *any* closed path.

Basically, the curl of a vector field, ($\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F$), tells you if a vector field is conservative or not.

If $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F =\mathbf  0,$ like for gravitational and spring forces, the force $\bf F$ is conservative. If $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf F \neq 0,$ like for magnetic forces, the vector-field is non-conservative. If the field is conservative, then $$ \oint \mathbf F \cdot \;\mathrm{d}\mathbf r = 0\;. $$

This is true for any conservative vector field.

Comment: Hi, Osmaan; welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar to the site. Also, don't write things like `this is my first answer here` ; it's a bit childish and irrelevent to the answer.